# Python IndexError list

Tags: python, arrays

I want to read data from an `.ods` file (using [`ezodf`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezodf/)), and convert it to JSON.

Here is my code:

```
try:
    while conf[i, 2].value != None:
        export_data['priorities'][conf[i, 2].value] = str(int(conf[i, 3].value))
        i+=1
except IndexError:
    print("This probably has a better solution.");
```

`conf[x, y]` references a cell in the `conf` sheet.  As you can see I want to read the values of column `i` as long as there isn't empty cell in it.

The problem is that the first empty cell is raising an `IndexError` exception.

Can I fix this in a simple way, for example, check the length of this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for (I'm assuming `conf` is a spreadsheet table):

```
for i in range(conf.nrows()):
   export_data['priorities'][conf[i, 2].value] = str(int(conf[i, 3].value))
```

But you should know that the `int(conf[i, 3].value)` bit will throw an exception if the spreadsheet contains a non-integral value.

There's nothing terribly wrong with your `try`/`except` method of doing this.